# Filtering objects OnLoad NHibernate IInterceptor

Tags: nhibernate, iinterceptor

I am having a problem loading objects using NHibernate. These entities have reference to files which no longer exist. When NHibernate assigns the 'Path' property of these entities these entities try to load the file which results in a an exception. The exception causes the loading transaction to roll-back completely.

I would like to keep my entities unchanged so they keep loading the file once Path is set. 
In the case that I am loading from DB i would like to skip these entities and load the rest of my project.

I was thinking about using an IInterceptor to get this done. Basiccally i would like to filter my file based objects before I load them.

I would like to hear any thoughts about similar problems and whether my 'solution' is feasible and possible.

Greetings,
Martijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try File.Exists(path) before loading the file ? Not sure I understood the problem.